# Behavior not understood in C program that prints out initials

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-statements, cs50

I have a simple C program that is supposed to accept a name given by a user and then print out the initials of the name in standard output. My implementation is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string name = GetString();
    printf("%c\n", name[0]);  // print out the very first initial of the complete name

    for(int i = 1; i< strlen(name); i++)
    {
        string blank_space = " ";
        printf("name[i] = %c \n", name[i]);
        printf("i = %d, blank_space = %s,strcmp = %d\n", i, blank_space, strcmp(&name[i - 1], blank_space));
        if (strcmp(&name[i - 1], blank_space) == 0)
        {
            printf("%c\n", name[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I give the program something like `Aug Koh` as input, then it should give me back `AK` as output. However, when I try debugging my program, I cannot seem to figure what is wrong with it. Here's the standard output from my program:

```
jharvard@ubuntu (~/pset2): ./initials 
Aug Koh
A
name[i] = u 
i = 1, blank_space =  ,strcmp = 1
name[i] = g 
i = 2, blank_space =  ,strcmp = 1
name[i] =   
i = 3, blank_space =  ,strcmp = 1
name[i] = K 
i = 4, blank_space =  ,strcmp = 1
name[i] = o 
i = 5, blank_space =  ,strcmp = 1
name[i] = h 
i = 6, blank_space =  ,strcmp = 1
```

All it does is it prints out `A`. What really puzzles me is why `strcmp(&name[i - 1], blank_space)` returns a value of `1` even in the case when `name[i - 1]` is a blank space, which should evaluates as the same as `blank_space` variable when doing `strcmp`. When I print out both of them with `printf` they both look the same!

Any help my problem here will be greatly appreciated, and I greatly value any suggestions for improvement.

FYI: This is actually from problem set 2 of the Edx course CS50. So `cs50.h` is a header file that is provided during the course which gives us special types like `string` and unique functions like `GetString()`.

Comment: Are you sure this is a C code?

Comment: I'm guessing there is some nasty stuff in `cs50.h`, like `typedef char * string;`, and a function `GetString()`.

Comment: strcmp isn't the right function. You're comparing " Foo" to " ". These strings aren't equal. Look at the `ctype.h` header instead to classify ascii chars. (But that cs50 header is evil. That string type is nasty.)

Comment: You need to compare chars not strings.  Your compare would only work if the value on the left was " ".  Which it never is.

Comment: Also, probably don't need to define blank space EVERY time in the loop.

Comment: https://cs50.harvard.edu/

Comment: What if the names have more than one space between them?

Comment: @Jiminion Good question, but at least for the purposes of PSet2, we were given a few assumptions to work on that included that the names would have at most one space between them. Also we can assume that names like O'Brien and so forth will not be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The less invasive change for your program (and there are many points to discuss) is to change `strcmp` into `strncmp` . Because `strcmp` compares strings of equal length as equal. With `strcmp` that will never happen because the first parameter string is always longer than the second (space). As your loop will never find the space, only the first letter will be printed.

Change:

```
   if (strcmp(&name[i - 1], blank_space) == 0)
```

to

```
   if (strncmp(&name[i - 1], blank_space,1) == 0)
```

If you want to compare substrings or

```
   if( name[i-1]==blank_space )
```

if you want to compare single letters.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you are checking for space incorrectly. It should be done like this:

```
if (name[i - 1] == ' ')
```

Comparing `strcmp(&name[i - 1], blank_space)` would work only when the entire suffix of `name` starting at `i-1` would match `blank_space`, a string with a single space character in it. This is possible only at the end of the string which ends in a space character, so it does not apply to your input.

Answer (score 2):

Here what you might be looking for:

```
int seen_space = 1; // The first character is assumed to be initial
for (int i = 0; name[i]; ++i)
{
    if (isspace((unsigned char)name[i]))
    {
       seen_space = 1;
    }
    else if (seen_space)
    {
        printf("%c", name[i]);
        seen_space = 0;
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: You need to reset seen_space.

Answer (score 2):

`strcmp` compares two strings till null(\0) for both strings is found and returns zero.

What you are doing is you are comparing `Koh` with  which is obviously not equal.

You should search for space like

```
if(name[i - 1] == ' ')
{
   \\space found
}
```